# Word for "moving on a ledge"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Is there a single word in English describing a sideway movement when one is walking with his back along a ledge?

One can see this frequently in movies. A person is high up on a building or in mountains and the ledge is so narrow one has to be with his back to the building/mountain and move slowly sideways.

Comment: In actual practice, people face inwards, even Harold Lloyd. Climbers call this 'traversing'

Answer (score 6):

> He [**sidled**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sidle) along the ledge.

moving sideways or obliquely.

Comment: In my mind at least, *sidling* implies a certain level of sneakiness.

Comment: A cute enough usage: "Sidling up to Uncle John" [Jason Levine ('delfuego')] http://www.flickr.com/photos/queso/3937350165/

Comment: There's symantics, there's pragmatics, and then there's indeed 'in my mind at least'.

Answer (score 4):

One could [edge](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/edge) along the ledge. This implies the sideways movement, as well as the cautiousness.

> 17.
>   to move sideways: *to edge through a crowd.*
>
> 18.
>   to advance gradually or cautiously: *a car edging up to a curb.*

Although  [*inching*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/inch?q=inching#inch__13) doesn't imply one's back is against the wall, it does imply the careful movement one would exhibit.

Perhaps use both!

> He edged along, inching his way back to the window.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the word [***inched***](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%20inched), meaning *to move along slowly and carefully*.

> He **inched** along the ledge.

Answer (score 0):

I looked up **slide** in the dictionary, which NOAD defined as:

> move along a smooth surface while maintaining continuous contact

That seems to fit, but the word itself conjures images of sliding down a slide, or sliding across some ice.  However, the thesaurus entry for *slide* had some promising candidates, including ***creep*** and ***slink***.

I might go with something like *carefully crept*, or *cautiously slid*.

Answer (score 0):

You can start making compounds like 'sidelong'
"toward the side," 1570s, alteration of Middle English sidlyng (see sidle) - OED
Bo turned and walked *sidelong* pulling the leash as heels clicked with a skip to glance behind, he then canted back forward with a tug.